# Can I prevent echo from expanding env vars?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, echo

I have an automatic setup script that is executed when a new user is created. It runs this line of code to set up the golang environment: `echo "export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"" >> ~/.profile`

But this will expand all environment variables before writing into the file. Is there a way to write `export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"` into a file from the command line without expanding the environment variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"' >> ~/.profile
```

*Single-quoted* strings in POSIX-like shells (such as `bash`) treat their content as *literals*, which is what you want here.

The only reason to use a *double-quoted* string here would be to *selectively* expand variable references *up front* - which doesn't apply in your case.

That said, here's an example:

```
$ echo "Honey, I'm \"$USER\" and I'm \$HOME."
Honey, I'm "jdoe" and I'm $HOME.
```

Backslash-escaping is used to escape embedded `"` and `$` instances that should be treated as *literals*.

---

As for what you tried:

```
"export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin""
```

is actually a string *concatentation*, composed of *3 separate strings*:

- `"export PATH="`, which, as a double-quoted string that happens *not* to contains `$`-prefixed interpolation elements, expands to literal `export PATH=`
- `$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`, which, as an *unquoted* string, is subject to additional [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), which not only involves expanding variables `$PATH` and `$GOPATH` to their respective values, but also applies word-splitting and pathname expansion (globbing).
- `""`, which amounts to the *empty* string and is effectively ignored.

Note how POSIX-like shells allow you to compose larger strings (concatenate strings) by placing strings - unquoted or single-quoted or double-quoted - *directly next to one another*.

Comment: the [chapter](http://www.linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0080.php) of a Linux tutorial with detailed examples addresses the issue very well, maybe worth taking a look.